# How to create two file in two difference physical volume of a volume group

Tags: linux, lvm

I have two physical volume (for example: `/dev/sdc` and `/dev/sdd`). I create a volume group (`VG001`) from the two physical volume, and I create a logical volume which take entire the volume group. From the logical volume, I want to create 2 files (after mounting it to a directory), each file in 1 physical volume. Is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that with the organisation you have created. Once you put both disks in the VG and created a single LV on top of it, you are at the mercy of the filesystem as to the placement of the files.